# golang - How to check multipart.File information

Tags: file-upload, go

When a user uploads a file using `r.FormFile("file")` you get a `multipart.File`, a `multipart.FileHeader` and an `error`.

My question is how to just obtain information about the uploaded file .  For example, its size, its dimensions if it's an image, and so on and so forth.

I have literally got no idea on where to start so any help would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file name and MIME type can be obtained from the returned [`multipart.FileHeader`](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader).

Most further meta-data will depend on the file type. If it's an image, you should be able to use the `DecodeConfig` functions in the standard library, for [`PNG`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#DecodeConfig), [`JPEG`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/#DecodeConfig) and [`GIF`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/#DecodeConfig), to obtain the dimensions (and color model).

There are many Go libraries available for other file types as well, which will have similar functions.

EDIT: There's a good example on the [`golang-nuts` mail group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/H_DZ3mmtY4U).

Comment: Thank you for that, mostly what I was looking for. How would you find out the size (kb, mb wise) of the file though, while keeping the file live for later use?

Comment: In the linked `golang-nuts` post, the example uses the `ioutil.ReadAll` function which is really a convenience function. For greater control you would use the `io.ReadFull` function which returns the number of bytes read. See http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll and http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull

Answer (score 21):

To get the file size and MIME type:

```
// Size constants
const (
        MB = 1 << 20
)

type Sizer interface {
        Size() int64
}

func Sample(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
        if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(5 * MB); err != nil {
                return err
        }

        // Limit upload size
        r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 5*MB) // 5 Mb

        //
        file, multipartFileHeader, err := r.FormFile("file")

        // Create a buffer to store the header of the file in
        fileHeader := make([]byte, 512)

        // Copy the headers into the FileHeader buffer
        if _, err := file.Read(fileHeader); err != nil {
                return err
        }

        // set position back to start.
        if _, err := file.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
                return err
        }

        log.Printf("Name: %#v\n", multipartFileHeader.Filename)
        log.Printf("Size: %#v\n", file.(Sizer).Size())
        log.Printf("MIME: %#v\n", http.DetectContentType(fileHeader))
}
```

Sample output:

```
2016/12/01 15:00:06 Name: "logo_35x30_black.png"
2016/12/01 15:00:06 Size: 18674
2016/12/01 15:00:06 MIME: "image/png"
```

Comment: I think that this is the best solution, as this code does not trust the client's information but checks the uploaded file itself.

Comment: This is the best solution, helped me a lot

Comment: Why use `file.(Sizer).Size()` instead of `multipartFileHeader.Size`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get approximate information about the size of file from `Content-Length` header. This is not recommended, because this header can be changed.

A better way is to use [ReadFrom](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.ReadFrom) method:

```
clientFile, handler, err := r.FormFile("file") // r is *http.Request
var buff bytes.Buffer
fileSize, err := buff.ReadFrom(clientFile)
fmt.Println(fileSize) // this will return you a file size.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way I've found pretty simple for this type of testing is to place test assets in a test_data directory relative to the package. Within my test file I normally create a helper that creates an instance of *http.Request, which allows me to run table test pretty easily on multipart.File, (errors checking removed for brevity).

```
func createMockRequest(pathToFile string) *http.Request {
    file, err := os.Open(pathToFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", filepath.Base(pathToFile))
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    _, _ = io.Copy(part, file)

    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    // the body is the only important data for creating a new request with the form data attached
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "", body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    return req
}
```